# Is there a way to have column O pull values from column F is J through L match A through C

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have column A as city code, B as Origin City,St , C as city code, D as Destination city,St. I then similar date in I through L with Carriers that haul those lanes in N. If a row in the I through L match a row in A through D I need the value of F place in the O column in the corresponding row.

I am trying to paste an image of the Excel grid, but I need column O to pull the value from column F from the row that has the values from A to D that match the data in a row in I to L.

[Expected Result in Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acLhS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of index() with match()

So, to fill Column O, this should work:

```
=INDEX(F$40:F$60,MATCH(I40&K40,G$40:G$60,0))
```

I have assumed that you can add a helper column in G, which is =A40&C40 dragged down.

I have also assumed that the combination of the two numbers in cols A & C are unique when combined.

If that is not the case then you will need to add col B, so the helper column becomes =A4&B40&C40 and the match will be I40&J40&K40.

Tested this on 3 values, as you don't give data I can get to.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I follow. I am not trying to fill 2 columns. A, B, C, and D have to be looked at as they go together. I,J,K, and L are similar, but there is an additional column with Carrier ID's that do those lanes, so in I through L there may be 3000 rows because there are many carriers that may do the same J to L. I just need O to get populated with the matching "Lane" from the lane ID which is column F.

Comment: That worked!! Once I added in the concatenated helper column, the Index then worked to match and pull the lane ID over. Thank you - Thank you - Thank you!!!

Comment: I was trying to. I can't find the Accept Answer button, or selection. It is probably right in front of my face, but I don't see it.

Comment: Look at the tick on the top left just under the voting number arrows - in grey until you click on it.

Comment: Hovering around, I found it. It's the Check mark. It would be nice, if it said Accept under it.